# Finding occurrences in a string and retaining the order of occurrence

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I've been using regex to finding different patterns in a string, which works alright, but I am losing the order of occurrence.

For example, when I am checking this string: `10£ + 5$ / 4EUR`, I would check if there are symbols and/or ISO codes and do some extra work on the side, which ultimately returns an array. But it's not sorted by occurrences

### Main method which finds all currencies

```
def find_currencies(string)
  currencies = []

  # check symbols
  currencies = currencies + currencies_from_symbol(string) if string =~ /\p{Sc}/
  # check iso codes
  if Currency.iso_codes.any? { |code| string =~ /#{code}/i }
    iso_codes = string.scan(Regexp.new(Currency.iso_codes.join('|'), true))

    currencies = currencies + iso_codes.map { |code| Money::Currency.find(code.downcase.to_sym) }
  end

  currencies
end
```

### Method to return currencies from a currency symbol

```
def currencies_from_symbol(string)
  currencies = Money::Currency.all.select do |m|
    string.scan(/\p{Sc}/).include?(m.symbol) && m.priority < 10
  end

  unless currencies.any? { |m| m.id == :usd || m.id == :gbp }
    return currencies
  end

  # Default to USD and GBP
  # TODO: Remove when default can be selected
  currencies.select { |m| m.id == :usd || m.id == :gbp }
end
```

`find_currencies` will returns, for example: `[#<Money::Currency id: usd>, #<Money::Currency id: gbp>, #<Money::Currency id: eur>]`, which doesn't correspond to the string original order. I need it to be `[gbp, usd, eur]`

I would really appreciate help on this. My current thinking that I need to do a lookup for symbols and iso codes at the same time to retain occurrence order somehow. But doing it separately would be better of course.

Comment: `currencies = string.scan(/\p{Sc}/).map{ |c| Money::Currency.find_by(symbol: c).where('priority < 10') }` ?
"10£ + 5$ / 4€" should be of order [gbp, usd, eur]

Comment: Just from looking at the Money gem's docs you might try `require 'money'; Money.assume_from_symbol = true; str.split.map { |s| Money.parse(s) }.compact`. I installed Money and found `Money::new` and other methods work, but `parse` appears to require that (some part of) Rails be installed. As I don't know Rails, I can't test. (Please try that and report the results in a comment.) I've assumed `parse` returns `nil` if the string can't be parsed. If it instead raises an exception that would have to be caught and `nil`be returned..

Comment: @kiddorails It's not an ActiveRecord class, but I've modified your approach which seems to work. I have yet to test more complex strings to see if it retains the order. Thanks!

Comment: @CarySwoveland `Money` dropped support for string parsing, which instead has been moved to `Monetize` gem which I do use. But it's not sophisticated enough but is something to explore. Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've adopted an approach suggested by @kiddorails, which seems to work so far. I've also split out some methods, but using all currency symbols and doing a direct `select` ended up retaining the right order:

```
symbols    = string.scan(/\p{Sc}/)
currencies = symbols.flat_map { |symbol| find_currency_by_symbol(symbol) }

def find_currency_by_symbol(symbol)
  Money::Currency.all.select do |currency|
    currency.symbol == symbol && currency.priority < 10
  end
end
```